# Python sample programs for FusionCharts to integrate with MySQL

Tags: python, fusioncharts

I want to integrate Python with FusionCharts and MySQL.

I have python programs to create/access MySQL DB.

The same data which resides in the MySQL DB has to be projected to the user in the FusionCharts using Python scripts.

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few examples out there

- http://bitbucket.org/schmichael/python-fusioncharts/src/tip/snippets/